# How to get HTML structure From a XML File

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Suppose the xml file is like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
<!ENTITY ldquo "&#x2665;">
]>
<DATA>
<ROW>
        <Id>29855</Id>
        <content><p>Did the summer fly as fast &ldquo;</p>
                  <a href="https://www.ex.com/" target="_blank"></content>
<ROW>
<ROW>
        <Id>11223</Id>
        <content><p>Fly as fast &ldquo;</p>
                  <a href="https://www.ex.com/" target="_blank"></content>
<ROW>
</DATA>
```

The requirement is to get the "id" and "content" from the xml. The content should come in html structure as it is present in the xml file. like :

```
<p>Fly as fast &ldquo;</p>
                  <a href="https://www.ex.com/" target="_blank">
```

I tried but i'm getting the content in a string format like : Fly as fast “

This is the code that i used to parse the xml:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("D:\\customer_connect_posts.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    /*System.out.println("Staff id : "
                                       + eElement.getAttribute("Name"));*/
                    System.out.println("First Name : "
                                       + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Id")
                                         .item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Last Name : "
                                       + eElement.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0).getTextContent())
                                         );
}
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

the issue is that i'm calling "getTextContent()" method which returns the text. Is there any other way to do this.
NEED HELP...

Answer (score 0):

To get text from html from DOM `Node`, you should to serialize it to html. You can do this with Saxon and use default `Transformer` [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635398/how-to-get-html-from-a-org-w3c-dom-node-in-java).

```
 Node content = eElement.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0);
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 Result result = new StreamResult(sw);
 TransformerFactory factory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
 Transformer proc = factory.newTransformer();
 proc.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
 for (int i = 0; i < content.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
     proc.transform(new DOMSource(content.getChildNodes().item(i)), result);
 }
 System.out.println("Content:" + sw.toString().trim());
```

And you shoud see next output:

```
Current Element :ROW
First Name : 29855
Content:<p>Did the summer fly as fast</p>
        <a href="https://www.ex.com/" target="_blank"></a>

Current Element :ROW
First Name : 11223
Content:<p>Fly as fast</p>
        <a href="https://www.ex.com/" target="_blank"></a>
```

And in your document tag `<ROW>` should be closed with `</ROW>`. Also applies to the `<a>`. But you can use simplified recording `<a href=... />`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **CDATA** or to encode the HTML to store HTML inside XML otherwise the HTML elements will be interpreted as XML elements. Also your `ROW` element doesn't seem to be closed.
I suggested using **CDATA** like this :

```
<DATA>
    <ROW>
        <Id>29855</Id>
        <content><![CDATA[<p>Did the summer fly as fast &ldquo;</p>
            <a href="https://www.ex.com/" target="_blank">]]>
        </content>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <Id>11223</Id>
        <content><![CDATA[<p>Fly as fast &ldquo;</p>
            <a href="https://www.ex.com/" target="_blank">]]>
        </content>
    </ROW>
</DATA>
```